# Carplay: UI is overlapping with left sidebar

Tags: ios, xamarin, carplay

I am currently working on arplay UI. But when  run the Carplay, UI is overlapping with left side bar. I have attached the screen shot as well.

```
UIWindowScene windowScene = new UIWindowScene(session, connectionOptions);
        
var ContainerViewController = UtilityIOS.CPStoryboard.InstantiateViewController("ContainerVC") as ContainerVC;
var registerController = UtilityIOS.CPStoryboard.InstantiateViewController("CarplayNavigationDashboardVC") as UINavigationController;

ContainerViewController.AddChildViewController(registerController);
registerController.View.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, ContainerViewController.View.Frame.Width, ContainerViewController.View.Frame.Height);
        
ContainerViewController.View.AddSubview(registerController.View);
registerController.DidMoveToParentViewController(ContainerViewController);
        
this.Window = new UIWindow(windowScene);
// this.Window.Frame = new CGRect(40, 0, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width - 40, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height);
this.Window.RootViewController = ContainerViewController;
this.Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();
```

[image]

Comment: Is the table view or the table view cell contents which are offset ?

Comment: Please, provide the correct language tag : this is not swift and does not look like objective-c

Comment: it is xamarin app. but the proces is same like native

Comment: Is this a CarPlay audio app? Why do you have to create windows and view controllers yourself?